# passing encrypted data into url and decrypted by php

Tags: php

this is my php code where i pass some data into url in encrypted form.

```
<?php 
$cancel = encrypt($_GET['id'] . '|' . hotel($_GET['id'], 'area') . '|' . $_GET['roomid']);
<input type = "hidden" name = "cancel_return" value = "<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/canceled.php?data=<?php echo $cancel;?>" >
```

this is next page where i fetch url data:

```
$custom_decrypt = $_GET['data'];
$res = decrypt($custom_decrypt);
print_r( $res);
```

this code for encryption and decryption:

```
    function encrypt($text){

        $salt = 'DFS65'; $key = md5($salt);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5($key));
        $encrypted = base64_encode($encrypted); return $encrypted;

      } 

   function decrypt($text) {
        $salt = 'DFS65';
        $key = md5($salt); 
        $data = base64_decode($text); 
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5($key)); 
        $decrypted = rtrim($decrypted, "\0"); return $decrypted; 
    }
```

but i got this result for decryption:

> 3�� =E��j���F�1tt����43a_ŋ Q4�

Comment: You're missing `)` somewhere here `<?php $cancel = encrypt($_GET['id']. '|'.hotel($_GET['id'], 'area') .'|'. $_GET['roomid']; <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/canceled.php?data=<?php echo $cancel;?>">`

Comment: thanx but still i geting same output.

Comment: You could look into open ssl. It has better support than mcrypt.

Comment: What @Nitin suggested is [good advice](https://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/simple-php-encrypt-and-decrypt/), also try replacing `data=<?php echo $cancel;?>` with `data=<?php echo urlencode($cancel);?>`

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

**`You errors:`**

- Missed php close tag `?>` of php script at first line
- value should be passed by `input` value tag
- receiver file url should be in `action` parameter of `form`
- name of var should be passed by `input` name parameter

here is you fixed code. It was modified for debug, so check it and updated for your needs

**index.php:**

```
<?php

$_GET['id'] = '1';
$_GET['roomid'] = '2';

function encrypt($text){

    $salt = 'DFS65'; $key = md5($salt);
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5($key));
    $encrypted = base64_encode($encrypted); return $encrypted;

}

function decrypt($text) {
    $salt = 'DFS65';
    $key = md5($salt);
    $data = base64_decode($text);
    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5($key));
    $decrypted = rtrim($decrypted, "\0"); return $decrypted;
}

?>

<?php $cancel = encrypt($_GET['id']. '|'. $_GET['roomid']);?>

<form action="/canceled.php" method="get">
<input type="input" readonly="readonly" name="data" value="<?php echo $cancel;?>">
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

**and canceled.php**

```
<?php
function encrypt($text){

    $salt = 'DFS65'; $key = md5($salt);
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5($key));
    $encrypted = base64_encode($encrypted); return $encrypted;

}

function decrypt($text) {
    $salt = 'DFS65';
    $key = md5($salt);
    $data = base64_decode($text);
    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5($key));
    $decrypted = rtrim($decrypted, "\0"); return $decrypted;
}



$custom_decrypt = $_GET['data'];
$res = decrypt($custom_decrypt);
print_r($res);
```

**output:**

```
1|2
```

Comment: The error is the wrong field name (`$_GET['data']` instead of 'cancel_return')

Comment: its up to you to decide what name of var should . my script is working simplified example

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=".......">
```

The input field name is `cancel_return`, but on the server you're trying to get unset property:

```
$custom_decrypt = $_GET['data'];
```

Which should actually be:

```
$custom_decrypt = $_GET['cancel_return'];
```

This (`$_GET['cancel_return']`) will return the encrypted value. Then, you can decrypt the value and use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the `data` value from the query in the decrypted URL.

```
$cancel_return = $_GET['cancel_return'];                       // Get the CORRECT value sent from the client 
$cancel_return_url = parse_url($cancel_return);                // Parse the URL that was passed to the server and return its components
parse_str($cancel_return_url['query'], $cancel_return_query);  // Parse the parameters of the query string of the url
echo decrypt($cancel_return_query['data']);                    // decrypt the 'data' parameter of the query string
```